# I want to delete first characters in a cell and show it in another cell

Tags: excel

I want to delete all letters before date `20-01-2016` in a cell

for eg:-

`19-01-2016` not well on `20-01-2016` he want leave
`19-01-2016` half day on `20-01-2016` not feeling well
`19-01-2016` chair broken on `20-01-2016` cup of tea

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is all the data in a single cell? Have you tried Excel Data Text to Columns?

Answer (score 0):

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHFyN.png)

Assuming that the data is all in separate rows in the same column as shown in the image provided something like:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("20-01-2016",A1)+1)
```

copied down column B would work.